# How to insert a recovery and root in HTC Desire 820 Dual Sim?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, twrp, htc-desire

I want to insert a custom ROM in HTC Desire 820 dual sim. I have unlocked the bootloader and tried to insert a TWRP recovery. I have tried multiple recoveries namely:

- HTC_A51_TWRP_Recovery_3.0.2-0_htcui
- HTC_D820_TWRP-Recovery-2.8.7.0-en
- HTC_TWRP_Recovery_All
- recovery.iso
- twrp-3.0.2-0-a32e
- twrp-3.1.1-0-a5
- twrp-3.2.2-0-a51cml_tuhl

While trying to flash these Unfortunately I Corrupted the OS. The first four of the above TWRP either won't get flashed due to

```
target reported max download size of 16777216 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magi
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 5736448 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
sending sparse 'recovery' (16382 KB)...
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 5736448 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 5736448 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
OKAY [  1.673s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: image error! (BootMagic check fail))
finished. total time: 1.689s
```

The other 2 flashed but when Executed the command fasboot boot twrp-3.0.2-0-a32e.img or the one with a5 the error is

```
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.356s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: dtb not found)
finished. total time: 1.356s
```

the last didn't give any error but doesn't work either( possibly because its a Desire 830 .img but its the only one not giving the error

the phone is (or was) android 6.0.1

```
A51_DTUL PVT SHIP S-ON
HBOOT-3.19.0.0000
RADIO-01.01.010_U10305041_08.01.51015
OS-3.17.720.3
eMMC-boot 2048MB
Apr 11 2016,21:16:51.0
```

It doesn't have an OEM unlock and I'm pretty much new to recovery and root stuff. Please suggest me how can I root this device too, so I don't fall into further problems. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/ for instructions to unlock the bootloader?

Comment: @Robert I have unlocked the bootloader from the official site and it is successfully unlocked.

Comment: @beeshyam i think it is not the official recovery as it mentions it for desire 620 and mine is 820 dual sim. I gave it a try though dosen't work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Very strange situation. I had up voted your question. Hope you get a solution